# PHP если есть ошибка то редирект

Tags: php

Как узнать есть ли на странице ошибка, и если есть то произвести редирект?

Comment: что значит "есть ли на странице ошибка"? Т.е на клиентской стороне? Или же в момент когда страница на стороне сервера формируется?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php), [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php), [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php) в связке с `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

```
function toHome(){
  header('Location: /');
  die();
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_error_handler('toHome');
set_exception_handler('toHome');
register_shutdown_function(function(){
  if(@error_get_last() !== null)
    toHome();

    exit;
});

// Fatal error
some();
```

**Внимание!**
Употребление редиректа подобным образом потенциально чревато ошибками в стиле `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
Так делать нельзя ни в коем случае.
Отловил, отправил в лог, вывел красивую табличку с ошибкой для пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // код
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Сначала ловите ошибки в try блоке, а затем вместо выбрасывания исключения делаете редирект (catch блок)

Comment: Вообще любая ошибка.

Comment: К примеру на странице могут быть разные ошибки, syntax error или не существующая переменная. Так вот, если обнаружена ошибка на странице, то редирект на главную header('location: /');

Comment: @asd поправил ответ.

Comment: как словить ошибку?

Comment: @asd не понимаю вас. Ошибка сама "словится" блоком try. Если в коде, который выполняется внутри блока try будет какая-либо ошибка, будет вызван блок catch, который, в свою очередь, произведет редирект.